# Add create new link in Yii Framework drop down list

Tags: yii

I am a newbie in Yii Framework and doing a small application in `Yii Framework`, I have the database for `Invoice` and `Customers` like this

```
   ==== Invoice ====
   id
   customer_id
   invoice_title
   invoice_no
   invoice_issue_date
   created_by
   updatd_by

   === Customers ===
   id
   customer_name
   address
   business_address
   city
   state
```

Now as per my requirment I need all the available customer name should come in a `dropdown` list in Invoice create form so I made changes in `Invoice form.php` to call all the available customers name like this

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($customers,'customer_name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropdownList($customers,'customer_name', CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'), array('empty'=>'Choose one')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($customers,'customer_name'); ?>
</div>
```

It is showing the available `customers name` from the `customer table`.But I need one thing more.That is it will show an addition link in dropdown called as `Create One`.Where the admin will click on this link and one `lightbox` will come with the `create customer form` where all the data  entered will be save in the `customer table`.I am also uploading some images for reference.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.Reference image has been uploaded here.[image]

**[Update]**
I have gone one step forward and made this changes

```
   <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($customers,'customer_name'); ?>
      <div id="job">
      <?php echo $form->dropDownList($customers,'customer_name',CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(),'id','customer_name'),array('prompt'=>'Select')); ?>
      <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('customers','Create customers'),$this->createUrl('customers/create'),array(
      'onclick'=>'$("#customers").dialog("open"); return false;',
      'update'=>'#jobDialog'
      ),array('id'=>'showJobDialog'));?>
    <div id="jobDialog"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

It is working But I want `create Customers` link inside the drop down list not outside the dropdown.So how to do that?Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Like I said, you can have multiple blank items in your select, and with javascript you can show/hide a dialog window if one particular item was selected. I updated my answer, I can't make it any clearer than this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an empty select item with the label New Client, like this

```
$form->dropdownList($customers,'customer_name', CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'), array('empty'=>array('choose'=>'Choose one','new'=>'New Client')))
```

and have a jquery function stand by, triggering a lightbox popup if the 'New Client' is selected.

```
$('your_select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'new') {
   // do something
  }
})
```

**UPDATE to reflect your update**

```
<?php 
  echo $form->dropDownList(
                     $customers,'customer_name',
                     CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'),
                     array('prompt'=>'Select', 'empty'=>array('choose'=>'Choose'), 'id'=>'customersSelect')
              ); 
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#customersSelect').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 'choose') {
             $("#customers").dialog("open");
          }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In this line `$form->dropdownList($customers,'customer_name', CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'), array('empty'=>array(''=>'Choose one','new'=>'New Client'))` the `New Client` is not visible in dropdown list.

Comment: I think it's because I did not add a value to the first option. Also, there was a bracket missing at the very end. Updated, try it now :)

Comment: The codes that you have updated is not working.It is not showing the option New Client.

Comment: Try using CHtml::dropDownList instead of ActiveForm's dropDownList. TBH, I tested the code with the former.